# DOMXPath union extract with PHP

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to get `img` and the `div` which is coming after the `div` which contains that `img`, all in one query.
So I did this:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[starts-with(@id, "someid")]/img | 
//div[starts-with(@id, "someid")]/following-sibling::div[@class="spec_class"][1]/text()');
```

Now, I'm able to get the attributes of `img` tag, but I can't get the text of the following sibling. If I separate the query (two queries - first for the `img` and second query for the sibling) it works. But how can I do this with only one query? By the way, there is no error in the syntax. But somehow the union doesn't work or maybe I'm not extracting the sibling content right.

Here's the markup (which repeats many times with another text and `id="someid_%randomNumber%`)

```
<div id="someid_1">
    <img src="link_to_image.png" />
    ...some text...
</div>

<div>...another text...</div>

<div class="spec_class">
...Important text...
</div>
```

I want to get in one query both **link_to_image.png** and **...Important text...**

Comment: Should work. See here: http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/8d416f7a-ced9-46b9-af31-bac77ed31848

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems correct.

Example XML:

```
<div>
    <div id="someid-1"><img src="foo"/></div>
    <div class="spec_class">bar</div>
    <div class="spec_class">baz</div>
</div>
```

Example PHP Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xhtml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//div…') as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node);
}
```

Outputs ([demo](http://codepad.org/y8aetuFM)):

```
<img src="foo"/>bar
```

Note that you will have to iterate the DOMNodeList returned by the XPath query.

Comment: I removed `/text()` and it worked (in a separate query). I think it's because `spec_class` div contains also html tags. But it still doesn't work with the union. It's really strange. I'll try to investigate more and will post the answer here (if I'll find it).

Comment: @msgdie When there is additional elements inside the spec_class div, it should work with `//text()`. The XPath module in Eclipse returns the text node then. However, it doesn't work in PHP, which might be due to PHP only supporting XPath 1.0.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work in PHP. Do you have any suggestion or any clue why it works perfectly in separate queries but not with union? What can probably cause such a behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, I checked the exact same markup (which I get from another site) with my xpath query, and it worked in http://www.xpathtester.com/test but not in my php code. Could it possibly be some php bug?

Comment: @msgdie I dont know for sure. I suspect it's either XPath version issue (PHP only supports 1.0) or a bug in the underlying libxml.

Comment: Somehow it didn't print the `spec_class` content when I was using `die()`. `die($dom->saveXML($node));` - I changed to `echo` and it worked. Thanks.